# PCA with correlated dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, pca, algebra

I am trying to describe the limit cycle of the waveforms of the 'arms' of a swimming alga in terms of the shape scores of its principal components. So I have the shapes of the arms stored in terms of xy coordinates at nodes distributed along the arc length of the arm. I am trying to do a principal component analysis on this, but I am struggling a bit.

Before, I had the shapes described in terms of curvature along the arc length. Each curve had 25 nodes, so I got a nice 25x25 covariance matrix. The analysis was very straightforward, everything worked fine.

Now for reasons irrelevant here, it is more convenient to have the curves described in terms of x and y values of the nodes. So 25 nodes with an x and a y value. So 50 features per sample, although features 1:25 and 26:50 form 'sets'.

This can be viewed as a matrix of *n* samples with *m* nodes with *k* features (3D), or simply as a 2D matrix with *n* samples with *k* features, where x and y are separate features.

Just chaining the x and y vectors and doing PCA on that did not really help me - I don't understand what I am doing anymore. I get the basics of PCA, but how to do this for a more complex data set is beyond me. Also, I am not too great at matrix algebra, so a more intuitive explanation is welcome.

**The question**: Am I doing entirely the wrong thing or is there some way to retrieve shape modes of 25 nodes with an x and y value?

Comment: maybe you can ask this in [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: it would help if you can decouple the PCA part from your domain specific application.. Right now the question is not easy to understand, at least to me.